# Multiprocessing: Use Win32 API to modify Excel-Cells from Python

Tags: python, excel, winapi, multiprocessing

I'm really looking for a good solution here, maybe the complete concept how I did it or at elast tried to do it is wrong!?

I want to make my code capable of using all my cores. In the code I'm modifying Excel Cells using Win32 API. I wrote a small xls-Class which can check whether the desired file is already open (or open it if not so) and set Values to Cells. My stripped down code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

class xls:
    excel = None
    filename = None    
    wb = None
    ws = None

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.filename = file

    def getNumOpenWorkbooks(self):
        return self.excel.Workbooks.Count

    def openExcelOrActivateWb(self):
        self.excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

        # Check whether one of the open files is the desired file (self.filename)
        if self.getNumOpenWorkbooks() > 0:
            for i in range(self.getNumOpenWorkbooks()):
                if self.excel.Workbooks.Item(i+1).Name == os.path.basename(self.filename):
                    self.wb = self.excel.Workbooks.Item(i+1)
                    break
        else:    
            self.wb = self.excel.Workbooks.Open(self.filename)

    def setCell(self, row, col, val):
        self.ws.Cells(row, col).Value = val  

    def setLastWorksheet(self):
        self.ws = self.wb.Worksheets(self.wb.Worksheets.Count)



if __name__ == '__main__':    
    dat = zip(range(1, 11), [1]*10)

    # Create Object
    xls = xls('blaa.xls')
    xls.openExcelOrActivateWb()
    xls.setLastWorksheet()

    for (row, col) in dat:
        # Calculate some value here (only depending on row,col):
        # val = some_func(row, col)
        val = 'test'
        xls.setCell(row, col, val)
```

Now as the loop does ONLY depend on the both iterated vars, I wanted to make it run in parallel on many cores. So I've heard of Threading and Multiprocessing, but the latter seemed easier to me so I gave it a go.

So I changed the code like this:

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import sleep

class xls:
    ### CLASS_DEFINITION LIKE BEFORE ###

''' Define Multiprocessing Worker '''
def multiWorker((row, col)):
    xls.setCell(row, col, 'test')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # Create Object
    xls = xls('StockDatabase.xlsm')
    xls.openExcelOrActivateWb()
    xls.setLastWorksheet()

    dat = zip(range(1, 11), [1]*10)

    p = Pool()  
    p.map(multiWorker, dat)
```

Didn't seem to work because after some reading, Multiprocessing starts new Processes hence `xls` is not known to the workers.

Unfortunately I can neither pass `xls` to them as a third parameter as the Win32 can't be pickled :( Like this:

```
def multiWorker((row, col, xls)):
    xls.setCell(row, col, 'test')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    # Create Object
    xls = xls('StockDatabase.xlsm')
    xls.openExcelOrActivateWb()
    xls.setLastWorksheet()

    dat = zip(range(1, 11), [1]*10, [xls]*10)

    p = Pool()  
    p.map(multiWorker, dat)
```

The only way would be to initialize the Win32 for each process right before the definition of the multiWorker:

```
# Create Object
xls = xls('StockDatabase.xlsm')
xls.openExcelOrActivateWb()
xls.setLastWorksheet()

def multiWorker((row, col, xls)):
    xls.setCell(row, col, 'test')

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    dat = zip(range(1, 11), [1]*10, [xls]*10)

    p = Pool()  
    p.map(multiWorker, dat)
```

But I don't like it because my constructor of xls has some more logic, which automatically tries to find column ids for known header substrings... So that is a little bit more effort then wanted (and I don't think each process should really open it's own Win32 COM Interface), and this also gives me an error because gencache.EnsureDispatch might not be possible to call so often....

**What to do? How is the solution?
Thanks!!**

Comment: You need two steps. One step to gather the data, in parallel, and then a second step to push it into Excel. If you can avoid automating Excel so much the better. If all you need to do is generate a file if data then you don't need an Excel process at all.

Comment: Excel is definitely needed as it is the visualizing tool (I'm working with usual office-using people), so the final data MUST be there. To your answer: So it's not somehow possible to write to the same sheet using multiple Win32 COM objects in multiple processes? I know it's probably not the best solution, but it would give me the smallest effort in re-structuring my code. I mean to first gather ALL data and at the end write it to Excel seems to be maybe the best solution, but coming from my serial approach listed above, you'll notice it'll take more rework like that.

Comment: *EDIT*: Would it be possible to using Threading instead of single Processes and therefore be able to use one `xls` instance for all the single Threads?

Comment: There is nothing that prevents you from using a COM object from multiple threads. As long as you make sure, that you follow COM's threading rules, by properly marshaling interfaces to and from the STA. Individual calls to a COM object are properly serialized. Excel does not provide a higher-level concurrency model, though, like transactions. Individual calls will get interleaved with each other, unless you implement synchronization into your controller application.

Comment: You don't need excel to make the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I know there are Excel librarys in Python, but I want to maintain the current file with all macros, all Cells formated individually etc... So I need COM interface to excel to ONLY write values to certain Cells, but apart from that, keep all other stuff...

Comment: Then the excel access part of the process must be single threaded.

Comment: Yes could be done by using Threads and then locking the part where I'm using my xls.setCell() method so that only one thread writes to Excel at the same time. But then still I have the problem that I dunno how to pass it to the threads cause it can't be pickled and I dont want to re-initialize the whole xls object within every thread on its own again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Excel can use multiple cores when recalculating spreadsheets, its programmatic interface is strongly tied to the UI model, which is single threaded.  The active workbook, worksheet, and selection are all singleton objects; this is why you cannot interact with the Excel UI at the same time you're driving it using COM (or VBA, for that matter).

tl;dr

Excel doesn't work that way.

Comment: Ok but: Yes but actually I don't need to work with multiple Excel Objects, I would even prefer to work only with one single Excel Object, but I don't know how to "share" that object to all the single processes as it is not pickable... It would suffice though

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to share it, since only one process can use it at a time anyway.  If you are doing a lot of work to prepare the data for Excel, you could pass that out to subprocesses and push it into the workbook from the main process.  If your data prep isn't significant, then it'll be better just to do it from one process/thread (because the overhead of communicating to the subprocesses is more than the gain).

Comment: Ok, some more clarification: The writing to excel is only a very verys minor part of every subprocess. Each process requests some HTTP-pages from the internet, so that part is the biggest performance impact which I want to parallelize. So even if only one process can write to Excel at the same time, this would be fine because the waiting time for other processes to finish the Excel-writing would only yield a slight overhead in comparison to the total amount of runtime of each process.

Comment: In that case, pass the work to the subprocesses and have them return the data for Excel to the main process, which has the xls object.  That case does make sense, and you only have one process talking to Excel (which is the only thing that would work anyway).

Comment: Ok, this would still take more rework to be done, but probably the best way for code maintenance and stuff like it. **EDIT**: And threading would really not be an alternative? Because from what I read and understood: Threads run all in the same process so would all know the single object `xls` and could therefore use it!? Ok I know for multiple concurring calls to writing Cells(), this could interfere with each other or block the single Threads, but one could also lock/unlock Threads right before and after the writing process..

Comment: @cco: *"one process talking to Excel [...] is the only thing that would work anyway"* - That's not at all how COM works. COM defines a concurrency model, and you **can** share COM objects across multiple threads. I wouldn't recommend doing it here, but it is technically possible. And in fact, concurrency is one of the reasons, why there is COM.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly true of COM, but that's not how Excel works.  I've both implemented multi-threaded out-of-process COM servers in C++, and have been driving Excel from Python for the last 13 years - I've been on both sides and have tried a lot of strange things.  The Excel object model depends on tying the active selection &c to the active UI objects.  The only reliable way to use Excel via COM is to ensure that only one thread (or process) is using Excel at given time.

Comment: @cco: I never denied, that synchronization were necessary. It is, since Excel doesn't provide any higher-level synchronization (like transactions). You can still have multiple processes talking to Excel, as long as you properly synchronize those processes. Your previous statement is inaccurate, unless you appended *"at any given time"*.